# Alternate format specifiers for long long in C

Tags: c, gcc, format-specifiers

Is there any other (alternative) format specifiers for `long long` in C other than `%lld` which can be safely used in `scanf` under gcc?

I am aware that `%lld` does it's job fine; I am just inquisitive :-)

Comment: It's not actually `gcc` that provides `scanf`, that's done by the C library.

Answer (score 1):

you can use %I64d... but it MS specific...

Answer (score 1):

From C99,
"ll (ell-ell) Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X
conversion
specifier applies to a long long int or unsigned long long int
argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a
pointer to a long long int argument."
So you can use "%lld" to specify long long datatype.

Comment: Are you sure "%ll" can be used safely ?

Comment: Sorry, you need to use %ll with any of d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier, so "%lld" is correct.